# Is it possible to detect an esp8266 in Google Assistant devices?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, google-assistant-sdk

Hi guys I'm creating a device that can be controlled by google assistant;
currently I created an arduino that interfaces with an esp8266 and through the service "IFTTT" I can communicate without problems. Now I would like to extend the project so as to make it public so as to find it in the "Home control" devices of google.
Is it possible to use "Arduino / esp8266"? How?
If it is not possible in this way what kind of board do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your device to work with the Google Assistant, you should consult the [smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). If your device can connect to the Internet, you're good. The ESP8266, since it already connects through IFTTT, will work for a more public project as well.

You'll need to create some sort of server backend which will act as the source of truth, responding to requests from the Google Assistant and dispatching commands to devices. If you can use the ESP8266 as a web server with minimal (< 5s) latency, you'll be set. Alternatively, you can use a simple service like Firebase.

Your web server will need to respond to [three primary types of intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app): SYNC, QUERY, and EXECUTE. The documentation walks through all of them, but they give you the ability to provide devices for each user, return the state of these devices, and send commands to do actions.